# How to set a (nice) linear-gradient from any color to transparent?

Tags: html, css, transparency, linear-gradients

I'm trying to set a linear-gradient on a div from red to transparent, but the output is a bit strange: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66U7K/).

Fiddle's css:

```css
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, red);
background:    -moz-linear-gradient(transparent, red);
background:     -ms-linear-gradient(transparent, red);
background:      -o-linear-gradient(transparent, red);
background:         linear-gradient(transparent, red);
```

As you can see, the transition between the two colors is in gray, while I expected only a red gradation.

Does anybody know how to improve this output (without replacing "transparent" by "yellow" in the fiddle)?

PS: tried in Chrome 23.0.1271.64

Comment: you can go to http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: the original behavior is actually correct: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparent-def

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Alright, this explains that, thank you for pointing it out ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try changing `transparent` into `rgba(255,0,0, 0)`

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9MpNM/

Comment: mm....out of curiosity....why it happens this way or any explaination for your answer to work??

Comment: you're setting a completely transparent red as first colour.

Comment: The Fiddle in Question & Your Fiddle looks same.

Comment: @Anup in what browser? I checked in ff 20.0.1 and they appear different

Comment: Can second that it looks the same in Chrome 31.0 on OSX 10.9

Comment: On chrome 31 / OSX 10.6.8 OP fiddle it's already fine. The issue doesn't affect chrome

Comment: This could be down to the version of chrome. 23.0 is a fairly old version (november 2012). it's at 31 as of typing this (also OSX - Dec 4 2013).

Comment: Seems like chrome is doing it wrong, firefox is doing it right, according to w3c spec, transparent is `Fully transparent. This keyword can be considered a shorthand for transparent black, rgba(0,0,0,0)` so a fully transparent black

Answer (score 0):

I have just modified your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66U7K/2/)

Check if like you want

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background:    -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background:     -ms-linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background:      -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background:         linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
```

Comment: this gets closer, but still this is not `red transparent` it is `white transparent` ;)